# Language Pack on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows

I am currently working on a Windows 2008 R2 server.
How do I check if the East asian language pack is installed on my Windows server 2008 box ?

Answer (score 1):

### GUI

Click the start menu and type "`language`" and then choose the Region and Language control panel:

[image: Region and Language]

Next, select the Keyboards and Languages tab, and click "Install / Uninstall Languages"

[image: Install Language]

Finally, click "Uninstall display languages"

[image: Uninstall display languages]

You will see a list of installed display languages.

### CLI

The only way I've been able to get language packs simply is with a three-liner in PowerShell, and it involves Get-WmiObject, so you know it's going to be nasty:

```
$OS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
$LangPacks = $OSInfo.MUILanguages
$LangPacks
```